How to solve 404 network error? I don't think any problem. Sure

@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/v1/login") 
@RequiredArgsConstructor 
@CrossOrigin
public class KakaoController { 
private final KakaoService kakaoService; 
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KakaoController.class); 

@PostMapping("/kakao-login") 
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> kakaoLogin(@RequestBody KakaoLoginDto kakaoLoginDto) { 

String code = kakaoLoginDto.getCode(); LOGGER.info("Get Code from FrontEnd : {}", code);
 LOGGER.info("Request getAccessToken()"); kakaoLoginDto = kakaoService.getAccessToken(code); 
String accessToken = kakaoLoginDto.getAccess_token(); 
LOGGER.info("access_token : {}", accessToken); 
if(accessToken != null){ UserDto userDto = kakaoService.getUserInfo(accessToken); 
return ResponseEntity.ok(userDto); 
} else { 
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null); 
}  
} 
@PostMapping("/kakao-logout") 
public String kakaoLogout(){ return "ok";
 } }

A project using react + spring boot is currently being deployed on a platform called cloudtype. The problem is that even though it appears to be calling the correct server address, a 404 error occurs and cannot be resolved. Currently, logs like the picture below occur on the client and server, respectively. The server is configured as above.
Currently, in React, code is passed by accessing axios.post as follows. What's the problem?
enter image description here
1import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
2import { useEffect } from "react";
3import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
4import axios from "axios";
5import Loading from "../layout/Loading";
6
7
8const KakaoLoginHandler = () => {
9    const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['userId', 'userName']);
10    const navigate = useNavigate();
11    const code = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("code");
12
13    const kakaoLogin = () => {
14        axios({url:`${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL}/v1/login/kakao-login` , method:'post',
15            params: { code : code} })
16            .then(response => {
17            const { id, username } = response.data;
18            setCookie('userId', id, { path: '/' });
19            setCookie('userName', username, { path: '/' });
20            navigate('/home');
21        })
22        .catch(error => {
23            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
24        });
25    }
26    
27    useEffect(() => {
28        kakaoLogin();
29    }, []);
30
31    return (
32        <>
33            <Loading/>
34        </>
35    );
36};
37
38export default KakaoLoginHandler;

I have checked URL... But I think it was correct!
